# How can I grep/pipe/redirect the output of tsc (TypeScript compiler)?

Tags: typescript, shell, pipe, io-redirection, tsc

My project consists of a very simple `index.ts`:

```js
const answer: 42 = 43;
```

If I compile it, I get an expected type error (with colors; not shown here):

```
$ tsc
index.ts:1:7 - error TS2322: Type '43' is not assignable to type '42'.

1 const answer: 42 = 43;
        ~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Let's say I want to grep for type errors:

```
$ tsc | grep "const answer"
```

I get no results. And no wonder:

```
$ tsc | wc -l
1
$ tsc | cat
index.ts(1,7): error TS2322: Type '43' is not assignable to type '42'.
```

Redirecting doesn't help:

```
$ tsc 2>&1 | wc -l
1
$ tsc 2>&1 | cat
index.ts(1,7): error TS2322: Type '43' is not assignable to type '42'.
```

How can I access the complete output of `tsc` in the terminal?

Comment: A parser to JSON exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aivenio/tsc-output-parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the `--pretty` flag:**

```
$ tsc --pretty | grep "const answer"
1 const answer: 42 = 43;
```

(Note that  ["`--pretty` output is not meant to be parsed"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16583#issuecomment-309200694), so use with care.)

It works like this:

```
$ tsc --pretty false
index.ts(1,7): error TS2322: Type '43' is not assignable to type '42'.
$ tsc --pretty true
index.ts:1:7 - error TS2322: Type '43' is not assignable to type '42'.

1 const answer: 42 = 43;
        ~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

**It's enabled by default, ["unless piping to another program or redirecting output to a file"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).**

You can also specify it in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "pretty": true,
    },
}
```